# Appmaker as Admin interface for Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-app-maker

I'm starting a new app using Firebase. The app has a consumer interface (mobile) and a business customer interface (web). To save time, I would like to use AppMaker to build the internal and business customer interface for the Firebase app.

Are you planning to integrate Firebase (auth, database) with AppMaker?

Comment: Are you having specific problem tying the two together?

Answer (score 2):

There are no plans in the short term to provide first-party integration with Firebase.

Note that I believe you could technically build an App Maker UI right now and connect it to Firebase using JavaScript, but it probably doesn't save you much time over writing things from scratch since you couldn't make use of bindings and a lot of other nice App Maker features.